# libcURL and Google Docs

Tags: c++, https, libcurl

I'm trying to download a file needed for my application off the internet (as part of installation) so that the first time the app starts up, the needed files get downloaded. For now I'm putting them on Google Drive and making them public, then I'm going to use libcURL to download them. The problem is, I just can't get the data.

I use the following link: `https://docs.google.com/uc?id=documentID&export=download` and replace `documentID` with the id. When I try connecting to the site though, it keeps giving me a small snippet of HTML code that basically says "Moved Temporarily" and gives me a link to the new URL. When I use the new link in my program, I get no output whatsoever. However, both links work just fine in my web browser, *even* when I'm not signed in. So Why don't they work in my program? Am I not setting up SSL options correctly, or is Google Drive simply not meant for this kind of thing?

Here's my code:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://docs.google.com/uc?id=documentID&export=download");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set the [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_easy_setopt) option to tell cURL to follow redirects.

Comment: I added the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION and set it to 1L, and I'm pretty sure it's making the connection, but now the program isn't giving any output...

Comment: To aid in debugging you can set `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`, it'll write a lot of debugging output to stderr.

Comment: Thanks for that tip! Now I know what's going on. So the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION did its job because when the first link gave it a "302 Moved Temporarily" code, it went to the new link. When it performed an HTTP request, it succeeded with HTML code 200 and got a lot of information which seemed correct. But then it didn't ouput the data for some reason... I think my `write_data()` function is wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this helps directly but I have always made the call

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
```

which I see you don't use. I have seen this call made here in the threaded SSL code example http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threaded-ssl.html. This `curl_global_init() call will perform SSL initialisation amongst other things. It is discussed in this link http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl and also in the libcurl tutorial here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html